# How do I isolate individual textures from my UV map

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I have recently gotten into texturing in blender and i have been trying to isolate individual textures from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I'm doing this so that I can add these textures to my asset library so that it'll be easier to texture future projects but I don't how to go about it

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure you can easily crop an image in Blender, you'd better do it in an image app like Photoshop or Krita

Comment: I was thinking of that but there are too many textures for me the do that for and it would take twice as long.